# How to pin Vimeo video

Tags: php, pinterest, vimeo-api

As I have use this code for sharing youtube video on pinterest. How can I share the vimeo video on pinterest?

```
<a class="scmPinterest w-socials-item-link" target="_blank" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create%2Fbutton/?url=<?php echo wp_get_shortlink();?>&amp;media=http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $valuesd; ?>/0.jpg&amp;description=<?php the_field('video_title') ?> "title="Share on Pinterest!">
    <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
</a>
```

Without javascript and without anyplugin. 
Youtube is giving the image of video using youtube api. How this can be done in vimeo?